# Maximal determinant of a matrix with $\| A \|_F = 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, determinant

Consider $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$. The sum of squares of all entries of $A$ is not greater than $1$. What is the maximum value of $\det(A)$?

Comment: Perhaps include what you have tried? You can write the determinant explicitly and observe it for a start.

Comment: answer's $\frac{1}{3\sqrt{3}}$... please include what You have tried

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** In terms of the singular values $\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3$ of $A$, we have 
$$
|\det(A)| = \sigma_1\sigma_2\sigma_3, \quad \|A\|_F^2 = \sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2 + \sigma_3^2.
$$